# View full site with cookies, javascript and mobile redirect

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I have a website(www.website.com) and a mobile site (m.website.com) and I'm trying to allow users to "View Full Site" if they want from mobile.  Currently I am using some Javascript to check screen width on full site then redirecting to mobile.

```
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://m.website.com";
}
```

This works fine.  On the mobile site there is a "View Full Site" button.  When you click this it redirects you to my script "force_desktop.php" which sets a cookie and then sends you to the main site.

```
<?php
setcookie("force_desktop", "1");
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com");
?>
```

Now that we set a cookie and redirected to the main website we need to check for the cookie instead of just checking for the screen width.

**Logic**

If Cookie force_desktop is found

Then exit

Else

run screen size test

Here is the code I attempted to use but doesn't work.  This code is placed in my head.php file which will be run on every page and is placed between the script opening and closing tags.

**Attempt 1**

```
if($_COOKIE['force_desktop'] == '1' {
exit;
} else if($_COOKIE['force_desktop'] != '1' {
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://m.website.com";
}
};
```

**Attempt 2**

```
if(isset ($_COOKIE["force_desktop"])){
exit;
else
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://m.mywebsite.com";
};
```

**Alternative logic that could work**

IF Cookie force_desktop is not found AND screen.width <= 699

Then redirect to m.myseite.com

Else

Exit

**Note**

I have run the following script to make sure a cookie is being placed, and it is.

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

I've run out of ideas and know my coding isn't correct, especially the If/Else statement within the If/Else statement.  I also am not sure if it is better to use the "isset" to see if the cookie is being used or ($_COOKIES['variable'] == "#").  I'd really appreciate some good feedback on this one.

**Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions,**

**Matt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing JavaScript and PHP. You're trying to use `screen.width` in your PHP script, which doesn't make sense. You need to use an echo statement to output the JavaScript into the page. It'll then check the user's screen resolution and do the redirect.

Try this:

```
if(isset ($_COOKIE["force_desktop"])){
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo '<script> 
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "http://m.mywebsite.com";}
    </script>'; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks Amal for your quick response.  I understand the logic behind this answer and that if it doesn't find the "force_desktop" cookie it will write (echo) the script that tests the screen width into the html .  However, I'm not sure where in the code to place this.  I placed this in my "head.php" file and have put it as is, in php tags, inside script tags and even saved it into it's separate  php file and used a php include to see if that works.  I just can't figure out how to properly implement this.  I hope you can help this novice a little more, Thanks again Amal.

Comment: @Matt: Simply add the script to the top of your full site's code and it should work.

Comment: Thank Amal for pointing me in the right direction.  There needed to be a "}" before the closing script tag to run the screen.width call, that is what was giving me so much trouble.  I also added a "}" tag before the else and "{" after the else.  Thanks again man, marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this test at the top of the php page, and for sure you cannot mix php and java script like this

u can alter this code like

```
<?php
 $flag = 0;
 if(isset($_COOKIE['force_desktop']))$flag++;
?>
```

later in the page use the code as soon as `<head>` tag starts

```
..
..
<head>
<?php
if(!$flag){
echo '<script> 
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://m.mywebsite.com";
</script>'; 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot mix javascript and PHP, javascript is front end and PHP is back end. Try something like this:

```
if( $something ){

   Header("Location: somewhere.php");

}
```